# How to Replicate this Postman Request which has a Binary Content Body and contains a .PNG File in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, postman, skiasharp

Here is the postman request I want to replicate in C# for my Xamarin App:
[image]

Here is how I am getting the image from my SKCanvasView:

```
        var surface = SKSurface.Create(new SKImageInfo((int)canvasView.CanvasSize.Width,
                                        (int)canvasView.CanvasSize.Height));
        var canvas = surface.Canvas;
        canvas.Clear();

        foreach (SKPath path in completedPaths)
            canvas.DrawPath(path, paint);

        foreach (SKPath path in inProgressPaths.Values)
            canvas.DrawPath(path, paint);

        canvas.Flush();

        var snap = surface.Snapshot();
        var pngImage = snap.Encode(SKEncodedImageFormat.Png, 100);
        AnalyerResults analyerResults = await mathclient.AnalyzeWork(pngImage);
        try { ResultString = analyerResults.message; } catch { ResultString = "Error..."; }
```

And here is what I already tried in C# to replicate the postman request:

```
            HttpClient client = await GetClient();
            var result = await client.PostAsync(Url + "analyzer", new ByteArrayContent(pngImage.ToArray()));
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AnalyerResults>(await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
```

Also I tried to use the code from the code button on C#. With modifying it I used:

```
        var client = new RestClient(Url + "analyzer");
        client.Timeout = -1;
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "image/png");
        request.AddParameter("image/png", pngImage, ParameterType.RequestBody);
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AnalyerResults>(response.Content);
```

However the response's content is null. Here is the header of my request:
[image]

Can you guys please help me? This question is related to [How to send image in C# to a Flask Server that is decoded by OpenCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62708339/how-to-send-image-in-c-sharp-to-a-flask-server-that-is-decoded-by-opencv). Thank you.

Comment: Click on the `Code` button (under the `Save` button, top right corner)

Comment: what are those 8 header values set on the request in Postman?  You are not setting any header values in your C# request

Comment: @SushiHangover with modifying the code from the Code Button I used 
            var client = new RestClient(Url + "analyzer");
            client.Timeout = -1;
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "image/png");
            request.AddParameter("image/png", pngImage.ToArray(), ParameterType.RequestBody);
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AnalyerResults>(response.Content); However response's content is null

Comment: @Jason I am not setting any header values

Comment: your screencap shows `Headers (8)` in the request

Comment: @Jason I added the headers in my post at the beginning